# A method should return an empty string, but it is not an empty string. What does it return?

Tags: java, string, phone-number

```
private String getMyPhoneNumber(){
    TelephonyManager mTelephonyMgr;
    mTelephonyMgr = (TelephonyManager)
            getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    return mTelephonyMgr.getLine1Number();
}
```

This method should return a phone number or `null`, but when I try to check the returned parameter, I see that it is not an empty string:

```
public void setMyPhoneNumber(){
    if (getMyPhoneNumber() == null){
        myPhoneNumberDialog();
    } else {
        myPhoneNumber = getMyPhoneNumber();
        toast(getMyPhoneNumber());
    }
}
```

What does the method return?

Comment: What you are getting in Toast msg??

Comment: @ Gnanadurai A nothing, empty toast

Comment: Try with if (getMyPhoneNumber() == null) Because null and empty both are different...

Comment: i tried and it didnt help

Comment: *What does the method return?* You tell us.  Debug it and see what you have.

Comment: have you tried: if ((getMyPhoneNumber() == null) || (getMyphone)

Comment: have you tried: if ((getMyPhoneNumber() == null) || (getMyPhoneNumber().equals("")))

Comment: You are assigning the value of myPhoneNumber but you never use it.
Also, it doesn't make much sense to have a setX() method without any parameters.

Comment: Print the value of phoneNumber in your toast method and call trim() on the String to find out whether you're getting back a value with spaces.

Answer (score 0):

> Returns the phone number string for line 1, for example, the MSISDN
>   for a GSM phone. Return null if it is unavailable.

[--Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getLine1Number())

`null` isn't equal to `""` (empty `String`).